# Ruby: Merging two hashes based on keys from one hash

Tags: ruby, hash, merge

I have two hashes

```
hash1 = {"a" => { "b" => {}, "c" => {}} , "d" => { "e" => {} } }

hash2 = {"a" => { "b" => {"x" => "y"}, "z" => 1}}
```

Now I want the merge to be in such a way that all the keys from hash1 are present in the final hash, and the value if present in the second hash should get merged and anything which is not there in hash1 should be removed.

So the output of this should be

```
final_hash = {"a" => { "b" => {"x" => "y"}, "c" => {}} , "d" => { "e" => {} } }
```

Comment: Could you show what have you tried so far?

Comment: Couldn't figure out anything. Tried something using the zip function, deep merge, but couldn't really get anything.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following, not pretty but here it is:

```
require 'pp'

hash1 = {"a" => {"b" => {}, "c" => {}}, "d" => {"e" => {}}}
hash2 = {"a" => {"b" => {"x" => "y"}, "z" => 1}}

final_hash = {"a" => {"b" => {"x" => "y"}, "c" => {}}, "d" => {"e" => {}}}

puts
pp hash1
pp hash2

class Hash

  def mittal_merge(source)
    result = {}

    keys.each do |key|
      value = {}

      self[key].keys.each do |sub_key|
        value[sub_key] = (source[key] || {})[sub_key] || {}
      end

      result[key] = value
    end

    result
  end


end

puts
pp final_hash
pp hash1.mittal_merge(hash2)
```

and here is the result:

```
{"a"=>{"b"=>{}, "c"=>{}}, "d"=>{"e"=>{}}}
{"a"=>{"b"=>{"x"=>"y"}, "z"=>1}}

{"a"=>{"b"=>{"x"=>"y"}, "c"=>{}}, "d"=>{"e"=>{}}}
{"a"=>{"b"=>{"x"=>"y"}, "c"=>{}}, "d"=>{"e"=>{}}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works for me :)

Comment: @AyushMittal you should accept this answer to give peter credit